# How to draw circles with radii given in kilometers accurately on world map

Tags: d3.js, maps, geo

I'm using the d3.geo.conicEquidistant() projection on a world map approximately centered on the Pacific, my aim is to draw circles from a point, illustrating a specific distance, say 1000km, from this point on the map.

**How can i calculate the correct radius on the projection, given specific kilometers?**

Here is my code example (yes, it's about missile reaches from North Korea. Using artificially Pyongyang as launching point :), building on this question: [Scale a circle's radius (given in meters) to D3.js d3.geo.mercator map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31573480/4623519)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
path {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 0.25px;
  fill: grey;
}
circle {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-dasharray: 5;
  fill: transparent;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var projection = d3.geo.conicEquidistant()
    .center([0, 5 ])
    .scale((width + 1) / 2 / Math.PI)//.scale(150)
    .rotate([-160,0]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var g = svg.append("g");

var missiles = [
  {
    name: "missile1",
    location: { // appx lat&long of pyongyang
      latitude: 125.6720717, 
      longitude: 39.0292506
    },
    reach: 1000 //radius of circle in kilometers on map
  },
    {
    name: "missile2",
    location: { // appx lat&long of pyongyang
      latitude: 125.6720717, 
      longitude: 39.0292506
    },
    reach: 3500 //radius of circle in kilometers on map
  },
];


// load and display the World
d3.json("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vida-public/geo/world-topo-min.json", function(error, topology) {
    g.selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries)
          .geometries)
    .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
});


svg.selectAll(".pin")
    .data(missiles)
  .enter().append("circle", ".pin")
    .attr("r", scaledRadius)
      /*function(d) {
      return d.reach
      })*/


    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + projection([
        d.location.latitude,
        d.location.longitude
      ]) + ")"
    })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I looked at this answer, trying it out above, but was not quite able to apply it to my code (i'm quite new to d3 to be honest, there might be something very obvious wrong):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31616927/4623519

Further question: is this solution specific to the mercator projection?

(Let's ignore that we really need to hide Antarctica in this projection.)

Comment: Can you link us to working code, or jsfiddle this somehow?

Comment: Here is a jfiddle i did after changing my code with Andrew's answer:  https://jsfiddle.net/y8qn8tr1/ - for some reason the world map path does not show in the fiddle...

Comment: Try https:// rather than http:// when accessing the geojson: https://jsfiddle.net/38he3mt9/

Comment: Ah, great, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this.

One (the easier option) uses d3's `geoCircle` functionality to create a geographically circular feature:

```
var circle = d3.geoCircle().center([x,y]).radius(r);
```

For this, x and y are your center point in degrees, and r is the radius of the circle in degrees. To find the radius of a circle in meters, we need to convert meters into degrees - which is easiest if we assume a round earth (The earth is only slightly ellipsoid, so this is an induced error of up to 0.3%, but even if using an ellipsoid, the earth is really more potato shaped, so that too will induce error). Using a mean radius of 6,371 km we can get a rough formula like:

```
var circumference = 6371000 * Math.PI * 2;

var angle = distance in meters / circumference * 360;

var circle = d3.geoCircle().center([x,y]).radius(angle);
```

This gives us something like:

```js
var width = 500;
var height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",width)
  .attr("height",height);
  
var projection = d3.geoAlbers()
  .scale(200)
  .translate([width/2,height/2]);
  
var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

var usa = {"type":"FeatureCollection", "features": [
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-94.81758,49.38905],[-88.378114,48.302918],[-82.550925,45.347517],[-82.439278,41.675105],[-71.50506,45.0082],[-69.237216,47.447781],[-66.96466,44.8097],[-70.11617,43.68405],[-70.64,41.475],[-73.982,40.628],[-75.72205,37.93705],[-75.72749,35.55074],[-81.49042,30.72999],[-80.056539,26.88],[-81.17213,25.20126],[-83.70959,29.93656],[-89.18049,30.31598],[-94.69,29.48],[-99.02,26.37],[-100.9576,29.38071],[-104.45697,29.57196],[-106.50759,31.75452],[-111.02361,31.33472],[-117.12776,32.53534],[-120.36778,34.44711],[-123.7272,38.95166],[-124.53284,42.76599],[-124.68721,48.184433],[-122.84,49],[-116.04818,49],[-107.05,49],[-100.65,49],[-94.81758,49.38905]]],[[[-155.06779,71.147776],[-140.985988,69.711998],[-140.99777,60.306397],[-148.018066,59.978329],[-157.72277,57.570001],[-166.121379,61.500019],[-164.562508,63.146378],[-168.11056,65.669997],[-161.908897,70.33333],[-155.06779,71.147776]]]]},"properties":{"name":"United States of America"},"id":"USA"}
]};

var circumference = 6371000 * Math.PI * 2;
var angle = 1000000 / circumference * 360;

var circle = d3.geoCircle().center([-100,40]).radius(angle);

svg.append("path")
      .attr("d",path(usa));

svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", path(circle()))
  .attr("fill","steelblue");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

The other option is to create a geojson feature on the fly from custom functions rather than through d3. The easiest way may be to take a point, and calculate the points that are x meters away at bearings spaced 10 degrees apart (for 36 points to the circle). This requires calculating a point using start point, bearing and distance, the formula can be found here. A while ago I built an example tissot's indicatrix using this method: [Tissot's Indicatrix Bl.ock](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/1e0a0d07b1a44aba4108c6cc70deecaa).

Comment: Great Andrew, thanks! This was super helpful. I changed my code to d3 v4 and was the able to draw the circles just as i hoped using the first, easier approach. This seems to work regardless of map projection? Where does the 6371 km come from? I will my edited code as an anser here.

Comment: I used the mean earth radius provided by wikipedia, though you could use the WGS84 specification for the major and minor axes of earth (or any other datum) and take the average of the two for a fairly close earth radius.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Andrew's answer, here is how i solved my problem:

Added styling, changed my code to d3 v4:

```
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        path {
      stroke: white;
      stroke-width: 0.25px;
      fill: grey;
    }
    .circle {
      stroke: red;
      stroke-width: 1px;
      stroke-dasharray: 5;
      fill: transparent;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**The d3 script:**

```
var width = 1200;
var height = 400;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",width)
  .attr("height",height);
```

Using the conic equidistant projection:

```
var projection = d3.geoConicEquidistant()
    .center([0, 20])
    .scale((width + 1) / 2 / Math.PI)
    .rotate([-140,0]);

var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);
```

Creating circles from Andrew's answer, one with 1000km and other with 3500km radius. These could be arranged more nicely into lists/objects i guess.

```
var circumference = 6371000 * Math.PI * 2;

var angle1 = 1000000 / circumference * 360;
var missile1 = d3.geoCircle().center([125.6720717,39.0292506]).radius(angle1);

var angle2 = 3500000 / circumference * 360;
var missile2 = d3.geoCircle().center([125.6720717,39.0292506]).radius(angle2);
```

Loading and displaying the World:

```
var url = "http://enjalot.github.io/wwsd/data/world/world-110m.geojson";
//display the world
    d3.json(url, function(err, geojson) {
      svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", path(geojson));
//append the circles
      svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", path(missile1()))
        .attr("class","circle");
      svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", path(missile2()))
        .attr("class","circle");
   });
```

Edit: Added https to the json file and altered the code so the circles are drawn above the world map. I have a working jfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/y8qn8tr1/2/

Comment: Questions in answers generally get few responses - being limited to comments, and limited in audience. Try `https://` for the geojson in the fiddle, and the drawing of the world happens after everything else is drawn - d3.json is asynchronous, either append the circles within the callback or use g elements appended in the specified order (outside the d3.json callback) and append features to those g elements (thereby ordering them).

Comment: Thanks again! i updated the jfiddle with https so it now works. This is my first question and still trying to figure out what the practise with follow-up questions is, I was a bit unsure if i was supposed to post a new answer or edit the original one and having new questions as comments. Maybe editing original was better? But this is maybe too off topic from my original question.

Comment: If you have a new/different question please ask it separately. You can always link to this question if you think it would add context.